# Como utilizar a class PDO nesta situação

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou utilizando a classe PDO para conectar a base de dados mas nesta situação em particular não sei como utilizar o PDO pois no parametro do mysql_fetch preciso de colocar uma variavel e pelo que pesquisei com a class PDO não é da mesmo jeito.

```
public function retornaDados($tipo=NULL){
    switch(strtolower($tipo)){
           case "array":
           return mysql_fetch_array();
           break;
           case "assoc";
           return  mysql_fetch_assoc();
           break;
           case "object":
           return mysql_fetch_object();
           break;
           default:
           return mysql_fetch_object()
           break;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A um certo tempo fiz da seguinte forma:

```
public static function selectAll($tabela, $condicao = NULL){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$tabela;
    if(!is_null($condicao)) $sql .= ' WHERE '.$condicao;
    try
    {
        $query = self::$conexao->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        self::erroLog(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Na linha `return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` entre os parenteses coloco o tipo de retorno que eu quero.

De uma olhada [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php) tem mais sobre os parâmetros. No caso as consultas retornaram sempre como o parâmetro especificado, no meu caso terei sempre um retorno na forma de `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.

Dá uma olha no [GitHub](https://github.com/IsaiasD/ArquivosPHP/blob/master/PDO/Banco.model.php) tem a classe completa.